# How to deploy a bug fix when a master is not ready to be released?

Tags: git, devops

Considering a continuous delivery strategy which merging to master deploys to QA and creating a tag deploys to prod, how can we fix a bug in prod but not releasing the last commit in the master (shown as commit Y below)?

Given the following git log

```
master
  - commit Y
  - commit X = tag 1
```

It was found a bug on the "tag 1", so we branch from that commit, fix it and merge back to the master.

```
master
  - commit Z with the fix = tag 2
  - commit Y
  - commit X = tag 1
```

Assuming that this Merge commit will be on the top, how to make sure the `commit Y` doesn't get deployed when trying to release the fix?

Comment: Your branching model is flawed. There are many ways to accomplish this, but a very common solution is to not allow non-production commits to the `master` branch.

Comment: I'd say the comment above is very opinionated. Your branching model is fine for a small team. However, the only way to accomplish what you want in your paradigm - is to branch out a release branch from tag 1 and only apply tag 2 on top of it, and deploy from that release branch. Assuming that such release branch will be short lived.

Comment: @tripleee we work with continuous delivery (not CI) and we have a bunch of automated tests to guarantee production-ready. I am just thinking hypnotically if for whatever reason it happens. We even have already plan for that(create a tag in a hotfix brunch) I am posting this here just to make sure we are not missing something.

I am curious to know what is your branch strategy?

Comment: A hotfix branch would work well, but then you don't want your CD pipeline to automatically deploy `master`. One approach might be to have a separate `deploy` branch.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You said `master` gets released to to QA, and tags get released to Prod. So if you branch off of Tag 1, and create Tag 2- that should go to Prod without commit 1 included. So, isn't that already what you want? Just deploy Tag 2...

Comment: @TTT in general tags job will be triggered only from master. Obviously, we don't want production release being triggered from any brunch

Comment: @AlexsandroSouza But you said creating a tag deploys to Prod. (Maybe you can clarify what you mean by that?) Tags aren't "on" any branch, they are "on" commits. So even if you wait until the tagged commit appears in `master`, as long as you deploy the tag and not `master`, you'll get what you desire.

Comment: @AlexsandroSouza maybe the confusion is that your log of `master` with tag 2 in it doesn't show the merge commit. As long as you tag the fixed commit, and not the merge commit, then you can deploy tag 2 and it won't include commit 1.

Comment: @AlexsandroSouza it just occurred to me that my last comment is probably what you were looking for, so I made it an answer.

Comment: I think there are some things to fix in your question. #1 After your bug is fixed and merge to master, commits in master will be (chronological order): `commit 1 , commit 2 = tag 1 , commit with the fix - tag 2`. In your question is `commit with the fix - tag 2, commit 1 , commit 2 = tag 1`  #2 Is this what you want to say in your first paragraph:  `Considering a continuous delivery strategy in which a branch called QA is used to test the application and if it is ok, it is merged to master, a tag is created and this tag is deployed to production, how can we fix a bug in prod but ...`

Comment: @TTT your right about the tag not be linked to a branch. I got confused because We have a job to create the tag and it is only available on post-merge to master pipeline.

Comment: @JRichardsz time does still go bottom up in the question, and C1 happens after C2 timewise. Maybe those commits should have been called something else to prevent confusion.

Comment: mmmm `and C1 happens after C2`,  1 after 2 ?? I think this is causing confusions. When you use `git log` you will see latest commit, previous commit, etc. You will not see oldest commit first

Comment: @JRichardsz I agree. I have edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just a little advice:  I do not quite understand this part `which merging to master deploys to QA and creating a tag deploys to prod`. Maybe is my english level :( . Do you think that this is the main idea: `which a branch called QA is used to test the application and if it is ok, it is merged to master, a tag is created and this tag is deployed to prod`. Anyway I think I have an answer for you. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @JRichardsz I think your proposal of a QA branch is a good one, but my interpretation of the described strategy is they code against `master`, build `master` and deploy that build to a QA environment, and once validated on QA, that commit gets tagged for a release to Prod.

Comment: It all makes sense. There are several reasons to not touch master until needed. This is the most important: It reflects your production latest code and stable features for your real users ready to deploy on production. So any commit or changes should have been thoroughly tested. That is why, common approach is to create a new branch from master when a developer will work in a feature or bug. I will thank you if you have us an example of the use of your strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you already solved your problem intuitively, but your graph isn't showing the merge commit so it isn't obvious in your question.

If you branch off of Tag-1, create a commit with the fix (commit `Z`), and create Tag-2 on that commit, after merging it back into `master` your graph will be:

```
MC (master)
| \
Y  \
|   Z (Tag-2)
|  /
| /
X (Tag-1)
|
|
```

As long as you deploy `Tag-2` instead of `master`, you will achieve your goal. Since your workflow is to release to Prod from tagged commits on `master`, if you decide you want to deploy Commit Y also, then you would put `Tag-2` on the merge commit (`MC`) instead of `Z`. Or, later after further testing, you could add `Tag-3` on `MC` to deploy it all.

As a side note, when you create commit `Z` on some branch, it doesn't actually matter what you name that branch, but conceptually you can think of it as a `hotfix` branch.